# Save output to a text file

Tags: python

The code provided runs with no issues and creates the text file, but it is empty. Need help to understand where the error is. If I run the code it runs fine, but as soon as I try to print to a file, I get empty results.

```
stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w+")

listOfFiles = os.listdir('s:\\')  
pattern = "*.txt"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            print (entry)

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin
```

The expected results should be a text file with the entries of all *.txt files and in what directory they are.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* mess directly with `sys.stdout`, because that's likely not going to behave as you want or expect it to.

While you *can* redirect stdout to a file inside a print statement, like this:

```
output = open("log.txt", "w")
print("hello", file=output)
output.close()
```

What you should be really doing is taking advantage of Python's context manager to write data to a file a a much more readable and maintainable way:

```
listOfFiles = os.listdir('s:\\')
pattern = "*.txt"
with open("log.txt", "w") as f:
    for entry in listOfFiles:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            f.write(entry)
```

Note that there's no need to call `f.close()` here, since the context manager (the line `with ... as ... :`) already does that for you under the hood.

Comment: Thanks @jfaccioni , added your code but get empty file and no errors

Comment: Then there's probably no matches between `entry` and `pattern` for your entries in `listOfFiles`. That's not a problem with saving the output to a text file, it's a problem with the logic of your program. I'd start by printing out what `listOfFiles` and checking if it actually contains what you expect it to.